# Strange behaviour of including Qt static library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

*I'm using Qt 5.15.2 mingw 64 bit.*

I compile a very simple static library and then include it to another qt app.

The strange thing is while compiling the app qt call MOC for every included header from the  library which has QObject derived class, and then compile moc_*.cpp file. Shouldn't qt already put compiled *.moc files to the library?

The problem is that it takes a lot of time for multiple files. But logically all needed stuff have to be inside the library, no need to run MOC for that files again.

Comment: How do you build your library? Have you told the build-system to include the object files created from the auto.generated source files in the library?

Comment: You must not add headers from your library to the HEADERS section in your pro-file when you use the library.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: I build it whith QMake. It makes all automatically.

Comment: @chehrlic: Great thanks to you! It works. Removed HEADERS as you said.